# Moment fromNow() not working as expected

Tags: momentjs

I have a date variable as follows

```
var date = "2016-05-31T20:03:21.000Z";
```

The current time is

```
var currentTime = moment(); //Gives Tue May 31 2016 20:24:46 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

But when I do `moment(date).fromNow()` it gives me `"in 5 hours"` instead of `a moment ago`.

`moment.utc()` did not help either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like moment is giving you the correct output here - you're comparing a UTC time (that's what the `Z` at the end signifies) to one in your local timezone. Should your `date` variable be `"2016-05-31T20:03:21.000+0530"` instead?